# Definition of quasi-static assumption

Tags: solid-mechanics

I'm reading [this paper](https://pangea.stanford.edu/researchgroups/supri-b/sites/default/files/spe119084-rss2009-JihoonKim.pdf), where atop pg 3, the author mentions the "quasi-static" assumption for earth displacements which leads to the mechanical deformation of a fluid-solid system to be governed by:

$$\nabla \sigma + \rho_h g = 0$$.

What exactly does "quasi-static" mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the author means that the equation does not describe a dynamical situation. After any change in the system, the density and the stress is assumed to come into equilibrium very fast (compared to the time-scale of the phenomena the author is trying to study). The dynamics of how this equilibrium occurs is neclected.

You could think of a weight suspended on a spring. If mass is added slowly to the weight then it is a good approximation to simply assume that the lenght of the spring is at the changed equilibrium position. Do it quickly however and the lenght will osccilate.